# Keras-VGG16-places365 low accuracy problem

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I'm using places365-standard datasets to train my Keras CNN VGG16 model. We change the output layer from 1000 categories to 10, which are 1.botanical_garden 2.cliff 3.creek 4.forest-broadleaf 5.islet 6.mountain 7.ocean 8.pier 9.skyscraper 10.temple-asia
Every category has 5,000 training images and the total of 50,000 training images.
The problem is after 10 epochs of training 50,000 images, we still can't break our accuracy through 20%. 
We will really appreciate if anyone can give us advice about why our model's accuracy is so low, thank you very much.

The model is as follow:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, nesterov=True)
model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(50):
        X = np.load( "C:/Users/firzen41616316/Desktop/numpydataKeras_1000x50/imgonehot_"+str((j+1)*1000)+".npy" )
        Y = np.load( "C:/Users/firzen41616316/Desktop/numpydataKeras_1000x50/labelonehot_"+str((j+1)*1000)+".npy" )
        model.fit(x = X, y = Y,
                  validation_split = 0.2, 
                  epochs = 1,
                  verbose = 1)
        print('Done training ', (j+1)*1000 ,' images')
    print('Done training 50000 images, Epoch ', i ,'  -------------')
```

Here is some parts of the print out:

```
Done training  47000  images
Train on 800 samples, validate on 200 samples
Epoch 1/1
800/800 [==============================] - 29s 36ms/step - loss: 2.3021 - acc: 0.1187 - val_loss: 2.3036 - val_acc: 0.1050
Done training  48000  images
Train on 800 samples, validate on 200 samples
Epoch 1/1
800/800 [==============================] - 29s 36ms/step - loss: 2.3036 - acc: 0.1037 - val_loss: 2.3056 - val_acc: 0.1100
Done training  49000  images
Train on 800 samples, validate on 200 samples
Epoch 1/1
800/800 [==============================] - 29s 36ms/step - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.1187 - val_loss: 2.3042 - val_acc: 0.1050
Done training  50000  images
Done training 50000 images, Epoch  9   -------------
```

Comment: Have you considered that your learning rate might be too high?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Hi, thanks for giving me advice, but I’m not quite understand your meaning by learning rate too high? Can you describe it in more detail? Thanks

Comment: You define your learning rate here: `sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, nesterov=True)` . He means that  you could try to lower it to maybe 0.01 or even lower and report back how that went.

Comment: 0.1 as learning rate is quite high, try 0.01 or 0.001. Also you should read the VGG paper about how they trained the model, it will give you the intuition about the parameters that were used for training.

Comment: To explain why: The easiest/ most effective parameter for better results is learning rate in most cases, which is why you always want to try different ones. With too big of a learning rate it's easy to oscillate around the solution, lower ones or more aggressive decay will prevent that.

Comment: Now I understand and thanks a lot, I will try changing my learning rate into 0.001.

Comment: Thank you all, I change my learning rate into 0.001, and now the accuracy is almost 30%.